# Best Practice for retrieving the data-attribute value in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about React Syntax. 

I was conceptualising a rebuild of my website in React and was writing code to access the `data-attribute` value.

The method I used to get the `data-attribute` value was:
`e.target.getAttribute('data-menuItem');`

and that seemed to work just fine. Upon further investigation I read about the alternative notation for the same method looks like:
`e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-menuItem').value`

I would just like to know if the second method I mentioned is best practice or if it really matters at all.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference (DOM-wise) between `getAttribute` and `attributes.getNamedItem` - both exists in all modern browsers and you can use any of them.

The [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) property returns a live collection of all attribute nodes registered to the specified node, while the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function gives you direct access to the value of the attribute you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, @Dekel. Is that to say that getAttribute is more performant because it is targeting a single attribute as opposed to accessing the key value of a collection/array?

Answer (score 13):

Let suppose that you have `<div data-pg="abc"></div>` in your html then in react you can retrieve data attributes:

```
let val = e.target.dataset.pg
```

Now your `val` will have `abc`.

To retrieve value of data attribute, alternative way is:

```
let val = e.target.getAttribute('data-pg')
```

Comment: The `dataset` should be marked as the right answer! This makes way more sense than having to use `getAttribute()`.